# Observable on Finally Callback

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscription, angular2-observables

Is it possible to create something like finally, but to subscribe to it?
Like:

- Observable1 (PUT on API)
- Observable2 (POST on API)
- ObservableA
- ObservableB

**If condition X**: Observable1.switchMap(return ObservableA).switchMap(ObservableB).subscribe()
**If condition Y**: Observable2.switchMap(return ObservableA).switchMap(ObservableB).subscribe()

Is there some way to do that without being repetitive on the second part?

Answer (score 1):

Observables don't fire until subscribed, so you can just do this:

```js
const obs$ = condition ? Observable1 : Observable2;
obs$.switchMap(...)
```

Or, if you prefer a single fluent chain, you can also use

```js
Observable.defer(() => condition ? Observable1 : Observable2)
 .switchMap(...)
```